# Criptografar Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, criptografia, web.config

Venho aqui com uma dúvida em relação a `ConnectionStrings` do `Web.config`.

Vendo que normalmente, informamos uma forma de autenticação na `ConnectionStrings` para a aplicação acessar a base de dados. E por padrão, qualquer um que conseguir acesso ao servidor onde a aplicação está instalada, terá acesso à base de dados, por meio dos dados contidos na `ConnectionStrings`.

Conheço a forma de criptografar utilizando o `aspnet_regiis`, para quem não conhece, um breve tutorial [pode ser visto aqui.](https://iisbrasil.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/criptografando-e-descriptogrando-strings-de-conexao-no-web-config/) Porém da mesma forma que estará "criptografado" os dados, basta utilizar o mesmo comando, apenas alterando o parâmetro que terá os dados "descriptografados" novamente.

Com base nisso, vem a minha dúvida: **Como criptografar a `ConnectionStrings`. do `Web.config` para esconder os dados de acesso a base de dados?.**

Comment: Você usa algum ORM para fazer conexão ao banco de dados?

Comment: @jbueno Nesse caso estaria com EF, mas se encaixaria com Dapper tbm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O ideal é não depender desta informação, seria melhor ter a autenticação feita por outros mecanismos mais seguros, como o [`Integrated Security`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString). Dito isto vamos à solução pedida:

Basicamente vai usar o utilitário `aspnet_regiis.exe`. Ele fica no diretório `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.Y.ZZZZZ`. Não se esqueça que deve ter privilégio de administrador para rodá-lo. Exemplo de uso:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "c:\diretorio\Web.config"
```

Não existe milagre. Criptografia não garante nada se você precisa que facilmente possa ser descriptografado. Você poderia prover uma forma customizada de criptografia mas precisaria ter uma chave e uma algoritmo para descriptografar isto. Se alguém tiver acesso ao seu `Web.config` provavelmente terá à sua aplicação que conterá ambos e será descriptografado. Então é melhor deixar o sistema operacional e o banco de dados cuidar disto. Eles farão um trabalho melhor embora um servidor totalmente comprometido pode dar acesso à qualquer coisa.

Mas se ele apenas conseguir ler seu arquivo `Web.config` ele não poderá fazer muita coisa já fora do computador onde ele foi criptografado não será possível reverter para o estado original. Esta criptografia é dependente do ambiente onde ela é feita. Por isto não adianta você fazer na sua máquina de desenvolvimento e copiar para a máquina de produção. A criptografia deve ser feita na máquina de produção sempre. Só lá pode descriptografar.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/zhhddkxy(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [Mais detalhes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178372(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esse utilitário eu conheço. Porém se alguém tiver acesso ao arquivo, poderá utilizar o mesmo novamente, apenas trocando o **-pef** por **-pd**, que consegue o valor original. Você teria algum exemplo ou termo para eu pesquisar sobre esses outros mecanismos que sitou?

Comment: Não existe milagre, por isto esta forma não é a melhor possível. De qualquer forma só com o arquivo não vai descriptografar, é preciso fazer na mesma máquina ou conseguir reproduzir as mesmas condições, o que é virtualmente impossível. Use [`Integrated Security`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Este método também eu conheço.
Agora essa parte de ter as mesmas condições eu desconhecia. Então se eu usar o **regiis** do meu computador pessoal para criptografar, somente se o computador possuir as mesmas condições que conseguirá descriptografar?

Comment: Como eu nuca usei isto não posso garantir, mas é fácil descobrir, faça um teste. Aí você me conta o que encontrou :) Editei a resposta para colocar mais informações, mas lembre-se que criptografia por si só não resolve todos os problemas de segurança.

Comment: Realmente, testei aqui e é exatamente isso. Bom, sei que não resolve tudo que preciso, porém já possuo uma segurança a mais. Obrigado pela ajuda.